Combining different data elements into one for use in top hosts Zabbix
I have different network devices (Juniper, Cisco, HP) in Zabbix, which use different templates for polling via SNMP. These templates have tests for polling temperature, CPU load, memory usage, but different templates use different keys for the same parameters. I would like to combine the same parameters on different hosts to monitor them in the dashboard via the panel "Top hosts". How can this be implemented?
